# Compiler says parameter cannot be converted from string to int, but it wasn't supposed to try to convert it

Tags: c#

I'm beginning to study C# with "Head First" series. I already began the exercise "Save The Humans" 4 times from scratch, but it simply doesn't work.
In the last time I did it,the problem is this: I wrote a method with four parameters, the last parameter is a "string". This method is called twice and the last parameter is "(Canvas.Left)" on the first call and "(Canvas.Top)" on the second.
It shows no problems on the first call. But on the second, it keeps saying that "Argument2: cannot convert 'String' to 'int'. I already counted the position of the parameters and everything seems to be in place. I checked inumerous times the code from the book and everything is just like the book.
What could be causing this? Here is the code:

```
private void AddEnemy()
        {
            ContentControl enemy = new ContentControl();
            enemy.Template = Resources["EnemyTemplate"] as ControlTemplate;
            AnimateEnemy(enemy, 0, playArea.ActualWidth - 100, "(Canvas.Left)");
            AnimateEnemy(enemy, random.Next((int)playArea.ActualHeight - 100),
                random.Next((int)playArea.ActualHeight - 100,"(Canvas.Top)");
            playArea.Children.Add(enemy);
        }
        private void AnimateEnemy(ContentControl enemy, double from, double to, string propertyToAnimate)
        {
            Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard() { AutoReverse = true, RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever };
            DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation()
            {
                From = from,
                To = to,
                Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(random.Next(4, 6))),
            };
            Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, enemy);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath(propertyToAnimate));
            storyboard.Children.Add(animation);
            storyboard.Begin();
        }
    }
```

Comment: How could you convert a string literal `"(Canvas.Left)"` or `"(Canvas.Top)"` into an int?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed a parenthesis in the code you posted.  You need to properly close the expression for the `random.Next()` function call:

```
AnimateEnemy(enemy, random.Next((int)playArea.ActualHeight - 100),
            random.Next((int)playArea.ActualHeight - 100), "(Canvas.Top)");
```

Comment: Thank you vey much. It's been 2 days since I began trying to write this... It finally worked... That's how it goes. Thank you again!